# cakephp v2. hide sql dump shown at the end of page

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am working on cakephp version 2. When I go to `localhost/blog/posts` (posts-database) and page opens then, at the end of the page, it shows me database.

Please let me know how to hide it.

Comment: You need to either turn off debug mode or remove the following line in your default layout `<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in *app/Config/core.php* file, just change

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

To

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

Alternative

Remove or comment

```
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```

in *app/View/Layouts/default.ctp*

Comment: Adding to this, you should always set debug to 0 when in production. If you do happen to have errors the inner workings won't be available for the world to see when it shows the stack trace.

Comment: If you have any database related changes, then you again need to change debug to 2, else your database changes won't appeared. Yeah, and don't forget to revert it back once all changes are working properly. Happy Baking :D